# NextJS app directory only project FOUC with console error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, emotion, chakra-ui

Just started a fresh NextJS 13 project with the app directory. I am using Chakra UI. I get a flash of unstyled content along with an error in the console. The page is my login page which my middleware redirects to when not logged in. I do have a loading in login page directory but it never shows up. [image]

my `package.json` file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/pro-theme": "^0.0.57",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.4.3",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@types/node": "18.11.10",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.5",
    "framer-motion": "^6.5.1",
    "next": "13.0.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.3"
  }
}
```

my `middleware.ts`

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import hasSession from "./helpers/gate/hasSession";

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for  the ones starting with:
     */
    "/((?!login|favicon.ico).*)",
  ],
};

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // if it is internal (like css etc), just allow it
  // console.log(request.url);
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next/")) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // Example function to validate auth
  if (hasSession(request)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const loginUrl = new URL("/login", request.url);
  // loginUrl.searchParams.set("from", request.nextUrl.pathname);
  return NextResponse.redirect(loginUrl);
}
```

root layout file under app

```
import Chakra from "../lib/ChakraProvider";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <Chakra>{children}</Chakra>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and the `chakraprovider` file

```
"use client";

import { ChakraProvider, ColorModeScript } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { theme as proTheme } from "@chakra-ui/pro-theme";

export default function Chakra({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={proTheme}>
      <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={"dark"} />
      {children}
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try removing all emotion and chakra packages and adding them back

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Just from experience, I also had one-time FOUC with emotion. As far as I recall, these packages can also be sensitive when installing them with yarn or npm.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and [this](https://griko.medium.com/prevent-fouc-on-next-js-chakra-ui-68df8b1b63ab) post help me solve the problem with the FOUC. As the author suggest: "*This happens because the Chakra UI stylesheets from  are not loaded server-side and only client-side*"

The solution: "*use @emotion/cache and @emotion/server to prevent initial unstyled content*."